# Query to select distinct name based on several factors

Tags: select

I have a table with the following data (simplified here):

### ID | PolicyName | Setting | State | Value

1 Default DiskUsage Enabled 1
2 Default Memory Enabled 1
3 Default CPU Enabled 0
4 Personal DiskUsage Enabled 0
5 Personal Memory Enabled 1
6 Personal CPU Enabled 0
7 Custom DiskUsage Enabled 1
8 Custom Memory Enabled 0
9 Custom CPU Enabled 1

I need to run a query looking for policy names that have Setting of DiskUsage Enabled and set to 1 along with Memory Enabled and set to 1.  So it should return:

### PolicyName

Default

Not sure how I can go about this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the data is constrained to avoid duplicates, how about something like this?  This is assuming Microsoft SQL Server syntax.

```
SELECT United.PolicyName FROM
(SELECT PolicyName FROM dbo.Policies 
WHERE Setting = 'DiskUsage'
  AND State = 'Enabled'
  AND Value = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT PolicyName FROM dbo.Policies 
WHERE Setting = 'Memory'
  AND State = 'Enabled'
  AND Value = 1
) AS United
GROUP BY United.PolicyName
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

RESULTS: Default

This specifically queries for each of the states that you care about.  Since there are two requirements, then the UNION will produce two rows when both selects are find a row.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!  This really helps out.  I'll look into UNION more as required.